# Germany: What to do if my visa appointment has been cancelled?

Tags: visas, germany, schengen-visas, study

The German embassy in Cairo cancelled my visa interview after I sent an email asking for an earlier appointment. No reason has been provided for the cancellation and they don't respond to my emails anymore. What can I do? I don't want to miss my master study this semester.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP needs to contact the Embassy for advice

Comment: We cannot answer. You should ask them. Are you sure that your write in your email  what you think you wrote? German can be very confusing. Email is not the best contact form.

Comment: If my level in German is C1 will you doubt I wrote a confusing email?

Comment: @Ammar Atef It doesn’t necessarily follow that C1 level means you always explain yourself clearly. What did you actually say in your email? E.g. ‘Can I have an earlier appointment?’ and ‘Can I have an earlier appointment because the existing one isn’t suitable/convenient/in time for my trip?’ are likely to get different responses. The latter might be interpreted as a cancellation request.